# How to publish CLR user defined function to SQL Server 2014 with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr, sql-server-2014

I have created a CLR user defined function with visual Studio 2012.

But I have SQL server 2014. The last Target Platform in project settings is "SQL Server 2012".

How can I publish a CLR UDF to a SQL Server 2014 instance using Visual Studio 2012?